# AutoMapper - mapping integers to int array

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map integers from a database to an int array, but I'm getting the error:  `AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 'Custom configuration for members is only supported for top level individual members on a type.'`

This is what I have:

Model:

```
public class Year
{
    public int[] Months { get; set; } = new int[3];
}
```

Mapping:

```
CreateMap<DataRow, Year>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Months[0], opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["Jan"]))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Months[1], opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["Feb"]))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Months[2], opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["Mar"]))
```

Anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to do something like this

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Months, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => MapFromRow(src)))
```

where you have a method

```
int[] MapFromRow(DataRow src)
{
    int months = new int[12];

    months[0] = src["Jan"];
    ...
    return months;
}
```

AutoMapper does not seem to support "dotting" into a property or indexing into an array.

If you want to go fully inline, you can do

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Months, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new int[]
    {
        (int)src["Jan"], (int)src["Feb"], ...
    }))
```

Comment: Thanks, but for the inline solution it's complaining about src[".."] not able to convert object to int.  src is the DataRow

Comment: I missed the explicit cast. Wasn't in front of a compiler at the time. Try the updated answer.

Comment: Yup I figured, I went with your first solution thanks!